# WebView methods on same thread error

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview

I have a android program (Java + html in a webview). I can call from the javascript to the Java code. But the other way around stopped working (after updating in eclipse).

So this is what I'm trying to do

- Make a webview   (worked)
- calling in javascript to AndroidFunction.test(); (worked)
- the java test() function call webView.loadUrl("javascript:helloBack()"); 
  (! not working anymore)

I tried to let it work with the WebView in the MainActivity, but it didnt work.

MainActivity.java

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        final WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        javascr = new Javascript(this, webView);
        webView.addJavascriptInterface(javascr, "AndroidFunction");
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");

        ....
}
```

Javascript.java

```
public class Javascript {   
    Context cont;
    WebView webView;

    Javascript(Context c, WebView w) {
        cont = c;
        webView = w;
    }

    // function called in the javascript by AndroidFunction.test();
    public void test() {
          // Breaking point!!!
        webView.loadUrl("javascript:helloBack()");
    }
```

Error:

```
03-24 11:47:50.103: W/WebView(21026):   at com.android.org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.handleMessage(SystemMessageHandler.java:27)
03-24 11:47:50.103: W/WebView(21026):   java.lang.Throwable: A WebView method was called on thread 'JavaBridge'. All WebView methods must be called on the same thread. (Expected Looper Looper{41ab68f8} called on Looper{41bb70a8}, FYI main Looper is Looper{41ab68f8})

03-24 11:47:50.103: W/WebView(21026):   at android.webkit.WebView.checkThread(WebView.java:2063)
03-24 11:47:50.103: W/WebView(21026):   at android.webkit.WebView.loadUrl(WebView.java:794)
03-24 11:47:50.103: W/WebView(21026):   at com.example.hellobt.Javascript.test(Javascript.java:24)

03-24 11:47:50.103: W/WebView(21026):   at com.android.org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.nativeDoRunLoopOnce(Native Method)
03-24 11:47:50.103: W/WebView(21026):   at com.android.org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.handleMessage(SystemMessageHandler.java:27)
03-24 11:47:50.103: W/WebView(21026):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)

03-24 11:47:50.103: W/WebView(21026):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-24 11:47:50.103: W/WebView(21026):   at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Thanks for the answer. I edited the function in my Javascript file like this:

```
private void test(final String s) {
        webView.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                webView.loadUrl("javascript:" + s + ";");
            }
        });
        System.out.println("javscript done..");
    }
```

Comment: In your edit you mention that you've changed your code based on (one of) the answer(s), making it sound like this still hasn't solved your problem - but there is an accepted answer. I suggest you make it explicit whether this solved the problem or not (or otherwise just undo the edit).

Answer (score 247, accepted):

The JavaScript method is executed on a background (i.e. non-UI) thread. You need to call all Android View related methods on the UI thread. You can achieve what you need with:

```
mWebView.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        mWebView.loadUrl(...).
    }
});
```

Which will post the task to run on the UI thread.

Comment: where did you add the snippet (mWebView) to your original code?

Comment: In the test() function, see my above question.

Comment: What if you need to return a value? eg return webview.getUrl? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29748782/android-returns-methods-must-be-called-on-same-thread-error @JohanHoeksma

Comment: Do you know how and when this problem occurred?  In my Nexus 5X(Android 7.1.1), it's ok, but some devices crashed.

Comment: how to pass a variable? I tried to add variable in  mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:test('" + MyData + "');"); but the value never get passed to javascript !

Comment: i love you hahahahah

Answer (score 18):

In my case nothing was shown in a WebView, so I prefer another way:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        final WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.map);
        webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(...);
    }
});
```

Comment: what is "runOnUiThread" please?

Comment: @Martian2049, it is a method of `Activity` to run in UI thread.

Answer (score 13):

**Java** version: You must to use **Runnable** interface and Post to **Handler**.

```
webView.post(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
             webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
          }
       });
```

**Kotlin** version:

```
webView.post(new Runnable {
   webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html")
})
```

Comment: The Kotlin version must not use the `new` keyword for initializing the `Runnable`.

Answer (score 3):

This can be come over by using the post method. Please go through below code.

```
 m_targetView.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            m_targetView.loadUrl(".....");
                        }
                    });
```