# Android returns methods must be called on same thread error

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I am trying to call a WebView method from a method which is called by javascript in the webview. Webview then should return value that is used within the method.

html event -> javascript -> jSinterface -> android method <-> webview

Apparently Webview runs in ui thread while js doesn't and webview's methods must be called from same thread. This method can be used to call methods from non-ui thread:

```
webView.post(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            webView.loadUrl("javascript:" + s + ";");
        }
    });
```

But I want to return result as well. `return webView.getUrl()` for example. How can I do that?

Comment: Can you explain where you want to return the value, and for which usage ? loadUrl is void.

Comment: public void getUrl() {
        Log.v("Webview url", w.getUrl());
    }      Error occurs when this method is called from javascript. @HugoGresse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, when you call methods from JS to the JavaBridge and then to your class from a non-ui Thread, you have to use listeners/callbacks. When you have done your `loadUrl`, call you listener to pass the desired String url.

In this Example, I've defined an an inner interface with the `onGetWebViewUrl` listener. I've registered the listener by implementing the interface in the same class, so I can call it easily.

For example :

```
public class WebViewProxy implement WebViewListener {

    private WebView mWebView;

    ...

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void onJsStuff(){
        webView.post(new Runnable() {
             public void run() {
                mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:" + s + ";");
                WebViewProxy.this.onGetWebViewUrl(mWebView.getUrl());
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onGetWebViewUrl(String url){
        // call method 2 with this url
    }

    public interface WebViewListener {

        void onGetWebViewUrl(String url);
    }
}
```

Comment: Javascript -> JavascriptInterface -> Android method1 <-> Android method 2 <-> Webview method. How can I return mWebViewUrl from Android method 2 to Android method 1? Currently it's returning null when I return mWebViewUrl. I am guessing mWebView is returned before webview assigns a value to it. @Hugo Gresse

Comment: if you are in the same class, and if you set `mWebViewUrl` before calling your method 2, there is not problem. Be sure so to call you're method 2 after the `mWebViewUrl = mWebView.getUrl();` @love_in_dreams

Comment: Method 2 is calling method 1, method 1 is setting mWebView and then returning it back to method 2:          public void method2() { Log.v("Url", method1()); }                                                                                                                    public String method1() {webView.post(new Runnable() {
             public void run() {
                mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:" + s + ";");
                mWebViewUrl = mWebView.getUrl();
            }
        }); return mWebViewUrl;}