# Best practice implementing JavascriptInterface using WebView in Android?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, webview

I have a crash report of the same error like in this question: [WebView methods on same thread error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22607657/webview-methods-on-same-thread-error)

There it is suggested to create a Runnable().

I don't understand why exactly this solves the problem. The error says "Webview methods on same Thread", but the answer suggests to create the method on the UI-Thread (Main Thread). But isn't the UI-Thread the one and only thread? Could someone explain this whole process in detail (considering I create a new Webview in every activity in the constructor)?

My code to implement Javascript functions/methods looks like this:

```
public class JS_Bind {
    private static final String TAG = "JS_Bind";
    private Context context;
    private AdvancedWebView mWebView;

    public JS_Bind(Context c, AdvancedWebView mWebView) {
        context = c;
        this.mWebView = mWebView;
    }
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void openActivity(String activityName) {
        try {
            Class activityClass = Class.forName(PACKAGE_NAME + "." + activityName);
            context.startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, activityClass));
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Invalid activity name: " + activityName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void makeToast(String toast) {
        Toast mToast = Toast.makeText(context, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        mToast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
        mToast.show();
    }
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void external(String url) {
        mTracker.send(new HitBuilders.EventBuilder().setCategory("Action").setAction("External Link: " + url).build());
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    @JavascriptInterface
    public String showToken() {
        return gcmToken;
    }
    @JavascriptInterface
    public int showUid() {
        SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("Pref", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        int uid = pref.getInt("uid", 0);
        return uid;
    }
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void buyPremium() {
        bp.purchase(MainActivity.this, PRODUCT_ID);
    }
}
```

Do I have to change EVERY function to this code ([first answer in the question I refered to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22611010/2829128)):

```
@JavascriptInterface
    mWebView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void makeToast() {
          // ...
        }
    });
```

?

By the way, this is how I create the webview in the constructor activies `onCreate` method:

```
mWebView = (AdvancedWebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
mWebView.setListener(this, this);
mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new JS_Bind(this, mWebView), "Android");
mWebView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);

if (!DetectConnection.checkInternetConnection(this)) {
    mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/offline.html");
}
else {
        mWebView.loadUrl("http://example.com/tw3/index.php?s=home");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But isn't the UI-Thread the one and only thread?

No. `WebView` has its own pool of threads. There can be [many other threads in an Android application](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#Threads).

> Do I have to change EVERY function to this code

Not necessarily.

First, I do not see how you are getting that error (`A WebView method was called on thread 'JavaBridge'. All WebView methods must be called on the same thread.`) from your `@JavascriptInterface` methods shown above. That error is when you call a method on the `WebView` itself, and you are not doing that.

You will need to use `runOnUiThread()` (or equivalent techniques) if:

- Your `@JavascriptInterface` methods refer to the `WebView` itself, or
- Your `@JavascriptInterface` try to do something else that has to be done on the main application thread (which will yield a different error message, as it will not be tied specifically to `WebView`)

Your `startActivity()` call might need to be called on the main application thread — I forget if that can be called on a background thread or not. Similarly with your `Toast` work — while I think that can be done on a background thread, I am not certain of it. It has been ages since I tried doing either of those things from a background thread.

---

Also, please only use your code if you control every single byte of what is being displayed in the `WebView`. Exposing `startActivity()` to arbitrary Web content has significant security implications.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I didn't list every JavascriptInterface function, so I only posted 2 to demonstrate. I'm not quite sure which of my functions caused the error. I update my question in 1 min to show you the rest. I also thought about using webview in an AsyncTask, would you recommend that? About the security issue: Should I create multiple hardcoded methods for every single activity then?

Comment: @Vaia: "I also thought about using webview in an AsyncTask, would you recommend that?" -- no. "Should I create multiple hardcoded methods for every single activity then?" -- that would be an improvement. Or, just validate the input, rather than blindly opening any activity based on the passed-in string.

Comment: @Vaia: You are not referencing `mWebView` anywhere. So, I do not see how you can be getting an error from it, but I also do not see why you have it around in the first place.

Comment: I initialized my webview with `private AdvancedWebView mWebview;` and pasted the code how I created mWebView in my constructor at the end of my question here. Sorry, maybe it's because English isn't my mother language, but what exactly do you mean by why I have it around in the first place? Thank you for your time, I appreciate it.

Comment: @Vaia: "I initialized my webview..." -- yes, but then you never refer to it anywhere. Delete that field. Or, paste in the methods where you *are* referring to it.

Comment: I updated my question at the end of it. That is what I wrote in my `onCreate` method. Is this what you mean?

Comment: @Vaia: No. I am referring to `private AdvancedWebView mWebView;` in `JS_Bind`. This would appear to be a useless field. You assign a value to it, but then **you never use that field** anywhere else in the `JS_Bind` code in your question. It would appear that you can delete that field.

Comment: Ohh, I see. Thank you! I also found out why the error occured. It's an activity that a user calls via a webview link on an earlier version of my app where the activity didn't exist in that specific app version. However, thank you very much!