# How to run webview.loadurl inside class WebAppInterface?

Tags: android, webview

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  private static WebView mWebView;  
  etc...

  // JS -> ANDROID
  public class WebAppInterface {
    Context mContext;

    WebAppInterface(Context c) {
      mContext = c;
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void fn1() {
      mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:jsfn('testing123');");
    }
  }
}
```

I getting this error:

> W/WebView: java.lang.Throwable: A WebView method was called on thread
>   'JavaBridge'. All WebView methods must be called on the same thread.

Comment: Your possible answer may be here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22607657/webview-methods-on-same-thread-error

Comment: Thanks Satan, will test it later..really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Callbacks from JavaScript through JavaScript interface object executes on a background thread where you can't directly update your UI thread. In order to post update in your UI thread you need to do the following.

```
@JavascriptInterface
public void fn1() {
        mWebView.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:" + s + ";");
            }
        });
}
```