# Kotlin: All WebView methods must be called on the same thread

Tags: android, kotlin, webview

This is my kotlin code:

```
class WebAppInterface(private val mContext: Context, private val myWebView: WebView) {
    @JavascriptInterface
    fun goToHello() {
        val myWebView = myWebView
        myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/hello.html")
    }
}

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val myWebView: WebView = findViewById(R.id.webview)
        myWebView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(WebAppInterface(this, myWebView), "Android")
        myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html")
    }
}
```

But it's crash.

> Caused by: java.lang.Throwable: A WebView method was called on thread 'JavaBridge'. All WebView methods must be called on the same thread.

How can I fix this?
I found a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22607657/webview-methods-on-same-thread-error) by searching but this was java code.
Kotlin and Java are compatible but did not run due to a syntax error. (I think it's because I don't know Kotlin and Java. Anyway)

I'm a JavaScript-based full stack developer and I don't have any Android knowledge so I only wanted to use webviews.
But this is also very difficult for me. (It's like the period of chaos when I first learned JavaScript.)

Please tell me the solution.
ps. If you have a good list of Kotlin's inheritance and scope concepts, please link.

Comment: Please try to comment `myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/hello.html")`from 'fun goToHello(...)' and print some log here and check if it crash or not.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should use **Runnable** and Post to **WebView Handler**.

```
myWebView.post(Runnable {
   myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html")
})
```

Comment: Thank. You are my savior.
The solution code shows how poor my kotlin knowledge is. 

Comment: Mention not. We are team here. 

Comment: `myWebView.post { myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html") }`

Answer (score 2):

**Try This**

```
mWebView.post(object:Runnable { 
public override fun run() { 
   mWebView.loadUrl("") 
   } 
})
```

Comment: i have updated the code in kotlin,also you can convert java code to kotlin using *https://try.kotlinlang.org/*

Answer (score 1):

As the link you posted here the problem is because

> the JavaScript method is executed on a background (i.e. non-UI)
>   thread. You need to call all Android View related methods on the UI
>   thread. You can achieve what you need with:

The kotlin solution is the following

```
    val myWebView: WebView = findViewById(R.id.webview)
    //Apply webview's properties if it's not null
    myWebView?.run {
        settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        addJavascriptInterface(WebAppInterface(this, myWebView), "Android")
        post {
            loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html")
        }
    }
```

As you can see here there a particular instruction here `run` this instruction is 
 a part of the kotlin's scope functions.

Probably this tutorial that is designed for javascript developers might be helpul to kick start with kotlin https://dev.to/cassiozen/kotlin-for-js-devs-part-1-5bld

Comment: Really thanks a lot. It is very goooooooood * 999 link for me.

Comment: I'm happy to help!