# How to force Android-WebView to Redraw/Re-Render immediately?

Tags: javascript, java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-webview

Basically the `JavascriptInterface` receive a Click event from `WebView`, then I need to change an HTML element multiple times, the problem is the WebView show only the last change, that's mean the rendering is not immediate.

**Question:** How to make `webview.loadUrl("javascript:updateProgress(20);");` take effect and change WebView content immediately?

**- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -**

Old question:

I have a HTML progress-bar in my WebView, I can simply update the progress-bar value by running `webview.loadUrl("javascript:updateProgress(20);");` this work fine from `onCreate()`.

```
// JavaScript in WebView
function updateProgress(percentage){

    document.getElementById('progressBar').style.width = percentage + '%';
}
```

Now, I have a class that send binary data to an connected BLE device, I toke the example from [Google BluetoothLeGatt](https://github.com/android/connectivity-samples/tree/main/BluetoothLeGatt), and I added a method to write to an characteristic (send data) in [BluetoothLeService.java](https://github.com/android/connectivity-samples/blob/main/BluetoothLeGatt/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/bluetoothlegatt/BluetoothLeService.java).

```
public void WriteCharacteristic(BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, byte[] data, MainActivity mainactivity){

    byte[] data_twenty_byte = new byte [20];
    int progress_count = 0;

    while(get_next_twenty_byte(data, data_twenty_byte)){

        characteristic.setValue(data_twenty_byte);
        mBluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(characteristic);

        progress_count++;
        mainactivity.webview.loadUrl("javascript:updateProgress(" + progress_count + ");");
    }
}
```

The problem is the WebView won't be updated (*Redraw/Re-Render*) while `WriteCharacteristic()` is running, the WebView Redraw/Re-Render only after `WriteCharacteristic()` finish, mean at progress-bar 100%.

Note: *I already tried `runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {});`*

My Question is, How to force `mainactivity.webview` to Redraw/Re-Render immediately ?

Thank you,

Comment: My guess is you'd want to run this `WriteCharacteristic` method on a background thread, then post the `webvew.loadUrl(...)` back to the main thread.

Comment: Right, `WriteCharacteristic` is a member of `BluetoothLeService` Class, and this Class is used as a service, `mainactivity.bindService(intent, this.mServiceConnection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);`

Comment: however, I will try now you suggestion, running `WriteCharacteristic` on a background thread.

Comment: Doesn't work, I even avoided all BLE stuff, just JavaScript click -> JS Interface -> Call MainActivity Method -> Do progress-bar update in a loop... still updated only at the end.

Comment: I tested all solution from this topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22607657/webview-methods-on-same-thread-error

Answer (score 0):

As noted in my comment, pushing the long-running process to a background thread, then running the webview update on the ui thread should do what you are looking to achieve. Here's a quick example that I threw together:

```kotlin
package com.example.myapplication

import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
import android.webkit.WebView
import kotlin.concurrent.thread

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var webView: WebView

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        webView = WebView(this)
        webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        webView.addJavascriptInterface(this, "app")
        setContentView(webView)

        val html =
            """
            <html>
                <head>
                    <script type='text/javascript'>
                        function updateProgress(progress) {
                            let el = document.getElementById('progress');
                            el.innerText = progress;
                        }
                    </script>
                </head>
                <body>                    
                    <p>Value: <span id='progress'>0</span></p>
                    <button onclick='app.startUpdates();'>Start Update</button>
                </body>
            </html>            
            """.trimIndent()

        webView.loadData(html, "text/html", "UTF-8")
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    fun startUpdates() {
        doSomething()
    }

    private fun doSomething() {
        thread {
            for (i in 1..100) {
                runOnUiThread { webView.evaluateJavascript("updateProgress($i);", null) }
                Thread.sleep(10)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but my project is on Java, and `startUpdates()` must be on `public class MyJSInterface { ... }` needed for `webview.addJavascriptInterface()`

Comment: I'm confident that you will be able to translate this to Java and move the function to your interface.

Comment: Sorry, but if I do that I will get the same Java code I already have. I will try create a small but full example to easily identify the problem.